# Differential Drive robot simulation in Drake

Tags: drake

I want to simulate a differential drive robot in drake. However, its not easy figuring out the closest tutorial to start as a reference. 
In addition, can drake incorporate sensors like RFID or magnetometer. Any help will be appreciated.

I do have sdf file of my differential drive robot.

Answer (score 0):

There is one example of [PR2](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/tree/master/examples/pr2), which also has a differential drive (DD). This example models the DD as three fully actuated joints: prismatic x, prismatic y and revolute theta. Then you can build a constrained controller to control the basis. By constrained controller, I mean the target position of (x, y, theta) should satisfy the differential constraint.

I have an ongoing [branch](https://github.com/huihuaTRI/drake/tree/050720_pr2_tutorial_idea2) that tries to add some controllers to the PR2. It's raw but should be able to get you started.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer. I really appreciate it. I have been able to port the urdf model and will be proceed the way you have in your code.